# integral over a cone

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ndarray

Is there a fast way (standard or via some library) to compute integrals over cones in python?

I.e. I have an array `A` containing some values and I want to compute and integral over an index cone specified by numbers in array `sliceNums`. I can do it directly:

```
n = 10; m=100                         # just as example
A = np.arange(n*m).reshape( (n,m) )   # just as example
sliceNums = np.arange(n)*2            # just as example
B = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    B[i] = np.sum ( A[i,sliceNums[i]: ] )
```

But this will be slow for large `n` and `m` being large numbers. Is there a faster way of computing `B`?
(`sliceNums` elements can be any numbers between 0 and m)

Comment: [scipy.integrate.tplquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html)

Comment: `A[i,sliceNums[i] ]` is just a number. Why you need to `np.sum` it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the explanation of the computation wanted, what do you mean by "an index [cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone)"?

Comment: @MadLee, I've missed a character which changed the meaning :(  It should be read as    B[i] = np.sum ( A[i,sliceNums[i]: ] ) .  I want to compute sums of parts (elements with indices >= some number) of rows of A and which part I take -- depends the row index.

Comment: Everything will be slow for a large amount of elements... Have you tried large arrays and saw a timeout occur? If time actually does not play a role, computers are human, too. They need to take their time.

Comment: @SvenKrüger I don't see what you mean. Of course everything will be somewhat slower for large arrays, but the slowdown maybe orders of magnitudes less prominent if there is a fast library that could help.

Comment: Is `A` obtained using a mathematical expression? i.e. do you want to integrate the function `A(x, y)` over a triangular region of the plane `x, y`?

Comment: @xdze2  sort of. I have a complicated mathematical expression and I need to compute many multidimensional integrals with this expression as integrand, using varying integration limits. I could just use np.cumsum and take necessary coordinates, but it would eat too much memory

Comment: if you have a function `A(x, y)` you could try using [dblquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html) (for double integration), Could you include in your question an mockup example for `A(x, y)` and the boundary functions `y_min(x)` and `y_max(x)` (which is actually `sliceNums`)?